# Connect to remote Maria DB server with port forwarding

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to figure out how to connect to a remote DB server that can only be reached from the webserver using port forwarding with putty.

Here is the setup: There is a webserver with IP 1.2.3.4 that is allowed to connect to the DB server using a private IP of 2.3.4.5 that is listening on port number 22280. Both servers are hosted at digital ocean.

At the moment i am developing a php based website, using xampp and the database that i use its reachable on localhost 3306.

The question is that is there any way to achive a connection to the DB server behind the webserver using port forwarding? I want to use the dev database on the DB server instead of the one on localhost.

Many thanks. Trix

Comment: This has been asked many time already. See for example [How to use PuTTY to tunnel to database](https://superuser.com/q/1394559/213663) or [OpenSSH tunnel and connect to MySQL](https://superuser.com/q/1243665/213663).

Comment: The reason why i am here because i went over those documentations and still couldnt seem to figure it out. Thats why i am asking for some help.

Comment: Your question does not even mention that you have tried something already, let only what did you try and what problems did you face. This way you will hardly get a useful help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PuTTY to tunnel to database](https://superuser.com/questions/1394559/how-to-use-putty-to-tunnel-to-database)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the web server has a user *trix* and you want to access the port locally at port *3307*, this putty call should work (may be you want to use the user *root* instead):

```
putty.exe -L 3307:2.3.4.5:22280 trix@1.2.3.4
```

Alternatively you can use the GUI:

- In the category *Session* in *Host Name* type *1.2.3.4*
- in *Connection - Data* fill in the username (*trix* in the example)
- In *Connection - SSH - Tunnels*:

  - In *Source port* type *3307*
  - In *Destination* type *2.3.4.5:22280*
  - Press *Add*
- *Open* the connection

You can also configure ssh keys, then you do not to type the password. But this is an other topic.

Comment: Well, this is what is already shown in the questions I've linked above.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I thought, because the questiner seems not to be so well versed in the topic, I can adopt the call to his example. But your links explain the it satisfactorily.